# Dart library: export a file from the test folder

Tags: testing, dart

My library's structure is:

```
mylib
  lib
    mylib.dart
    src
      example.dart
  test
    utilities.dart
```

I'd like to export some helper functions I've written in this library so they can be used in the test files of other libraries.

In mylib.dart, which contains exports for the other classes in the library (e.g. `export 'src/example.dart';`, the following line causes an error:

`export '../test/utilities.dart';`

The error is:

`Target of URI doesn't exist: '../test/utilities.dart'.`

It seems I can only export files under the `lib` folder. I imagine this is a security thing, so I don't go exporting files from just anywhere on my computer.

Is it possible to export a file that contains utility functions for tests, if that file lives under the `test` folder? Or should I put those utility functions in a file under the `lib` folder, even though they only pertain to testing, and should only be used in other libraries' tests?

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it. That was my error in posting to StackOverflow, the file was serialization_testing.dart the whole time, but for StackOverflow purposes I changed the name to utilities.dart.

Answer (score 2):

If you have test code that you want to share in tests for *other packages*, you should put your code in the `lib/` directory (or in its own package) and expect that non-testing code would just not bother `import`ing it.

If you have test code that you want to share in tests in *the same package*, you can leave it in your `test/` directory (or in a subdirectory), and test files in `test/` can `import` it via the relative path.